# How to read the large number of inputs from console in Java?

Tags: java, java-io

I want to know the fastest way to read the large number of inputs from the console in Java. Number of inputs in range of thousands to millions. One way I know is using the BufferedReader to read a line from the console and then splitting the string read on delimiters to get the individual inputs.

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
String line[] = br.readLine().split(" ");
```

And then I can store the individual elements in some array. 
But suppose in one line I have thousands or millions of different inputs separated by a space or some delimiter, what will be then the most efficient way of doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A better way would be to save the long list of input parameters in some file and pass the file location as the single parameter to your program.

Later you can read that file to extract the parameter values.
Also, you could pass the delimiter itself as one of the parameter to reuse the code in case the delimiter is changed.